# Passing 2 models to the ASP.NET Core 5 view

Tags: asp.net-core-5.0

I am new to `IdentityDbContext`, I am working on a User Registration view, in this view roles should come dynamically from `IdentityRoles` table. In HttpGet I am passing a `commonViewModel` for
`RegisterViewModel` and `IdentityRoles` as shown below.

```
// CommomViewModel for IdentityRoles and RegisterViewModel
public class CommonViewModel
{
    public RegisterViewModel Registermodel { get; set; }

    public IList<IdentityRole> IdentityRoles { get; set; }
}

// RegisterViewModel
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
    [Compare("Password",
        ErrorMessage = "Password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

    public string RoleId { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my `HttpGet` action method for UserRegistration view:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult UserRegistration()
    {
        RegistrationViewModel Registration = new RegistrationViewModel();
        Registration.IdentityRoles = authenticationService.GetRoles();
        return View(Registration);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> UserRegistration(RegistrationViewModel registrationModel)
    {
        RegisterViewModel registerRecord = new RegisterViewModel();
        registerRecord = registrationModel.Registermodel;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new IdentityUser()
            {
                UserName = registerRecord.Email,
                Email = registerRecord.Email
            };

            var result = await userManager.CreateAsync(user, registerRecord.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            foreach (var error in result.Errors)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, error.Description);
            }
        }

        return View();
    }
```

This is my `UserRegistration.cshtml`:

```
@model IdentityPOC.ViewModels.RegistrationViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "User Registration";
}

<h1>User Registration</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Registermodel.Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Registermodel.Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Registermodel.Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Registermodel.Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Registermodel.Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Registermodel.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Registermodel.ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="Registermodel.ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Registermodel.ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="">
                    @foreach (var role in Model.IdentityRoles)
                    {
                        <nav class="d-inline-block p-2">


                        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Registermodel.RoleId, role.Id)@role.Name
                            </nav>
                    
                }
                </div>
                </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

My dependency injection setup in `Startup.cs`:

```
services.AddIdentityCore<IdentityUser>()
        .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityPOCContext>();
```

I am successfully registering the user but when password is not meeting the requirement it should render the view again with error message. In this case I am facing problem in my view as I am common model to view in get this is getting roles from db but when we calling again it is saying Identity Roles are null at the below point.

```
@foreach (var role in Model.IdentityRoles)
{
    <nav class="d-inline-block p-2">
        @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.Registermodel.RoleId, role.Id)@role.Name
    </nav>
 }
```

Please give me some insights on how to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved the issue by directly injecting the RoleManager into UserRegistration.cshtml as shown below, but I want to know is the standard way to do it.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity

@model IdentityPOC.ViewModels.RegisterViewModel

@inject RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager

@{

    ViewBag.Title = "User Registration";

}

<h1>User Registration</h1>

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Email"></label>
                <input asp-for="Email" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Email" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Password"></label>
                <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ConfirmPassword"></label>
                <input asp-for="ConfirmPassword" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="ConfirmPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div class="">
                    @{IQueryable<IdentityRole> roles = roleManager.Roles;
                        @foreach (var role in roles)
                        {
                            <nav class="d-inline-block p-2">
                                @Html.RadioButtonFor(m => m.RoleId, role.Id)@role.Name
                            </nav>
                            }
                        }
                </div>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```